# How to export SVM model with custom kernel?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, joblib

I write my custom kernel and trained the SVM model with it. I use

`joblib.dump(model,"model.joblib")`

to export the model. But I cannot load the model using joblib in the Django server due to

"module '**main**' has no attribute mycustomkernel" error. The code is shown below, the file path is correct:

```
import joblib 
from pathlib import Path
import os
path = os.path.join(Path(__file__).resolve().parent , 'static/model.joblib')
model = joblib.load(path)`
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share how you load the model using `joblib`?

Comment: Hi @TobiasWindisch, Thank you for the reply! I update the question and post my code,